# Where I can find the "62 volumes of common Hadiths between Sunni & Shia" which was unveiled at the 28th International Islamic Unity Conference

Tags: hadith, authenticity, uloom-al-hadith, shia-sunni, sahaba

The links in Arabic are below.   Just trying to see if anyone knows the name of the book(s) or where I can find more information online.

https://www.tasnimnews.com/fa/news/1393/12/18/680140

https://www.isna.ir/news/93101709497/

Comment: These sites are in Persian language not Arabic.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.